# How to Store Multiple Arrays Returned From Pthread in Another Array Using Pointers

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, concurrency, pthreads

I'm working on a project that needs to run multiple threads concurrently. Each thread runs a function that returns a pointer to an array of ints (cast as a void pointer). For example, in the function that the threads run, the values I want are stored as such:

```
void *func(void *args) {
    int vals[3] = {0, 0, 0}, x = y = z = 0;
    int *ptr = vals;

    while(condition) {
        .
        .
        .
        ptr[0] += x;
        ptr[1] += y;
        ptr[2] += z;
    }
    return (void *) ptr;
}
```

By the end of this function, ptr[0], ptr[1], and ptr[2] hold the desired values. This code is just to give you an idea of whats happening, there is nothing wrong with my actual implementation.

I am required to use pthread_join() to get the various values from each thread. Each thread handles one file, so # of files == # of threads == # of times the above function runs.

I need to take the values of ptr[0], ptr[1], and ptr[2] from each thread and add them together once they are returned to main. Meaning if there are three threads, then I need to add ptr[0] from thread 1 to ptr[0] from thread 2 and ptr[0] from thread 3. The same thing goes for ptr[1] and ptr[2]. Then I need to print the three total values in main at the end. So far this is how I've done it and I got my code to compile but the values are garbage.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int NUM_THREADS = argc - 1;
    int total1 = total2 = total3 = 0;
    pthread_t *tids; /* Dynamically allocated array of pthreads */
    void **vals; /* Stores the return values from each thread, this could be incorrect */

    /*
    ** Some code where I allocate the arrays etc
    */

    for (i= 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
      pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, func, NULL);

    for (i= 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
      pthread_join(tids[i], &(vals[i])); /* Again, this could be wrong */

    for (i= 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
      total1 += ((int*) vals[i])[0]; /* These statements very well could also be wrong */
      total2 += ((int*) vals[i])[1];
      total3 += ((int*) vals[i])[2];
    }

    /* Print totals */

    return 0;
}
```

I know the values in each thread are correct at the end of func, but I don't know how to properly store, process, and print them in main.

Also, I am using C90 and cannot use any functionality from any other version of C and I must store the values using pthread_join().

Answer (score 0):

> Each thread runs a function that returns a pointer to an array of ints (cast as a void pointer). For example
>
> ```
> void *func(void *args) {
>     int vals[3] = {0, 0, 0}, x = y = z = 0;
>     int *ptr = vals;
> ...
>     return (void *) ptr;
> }
> ```

You should start by fixing the function to return something meaningful. As currently written, the function returns a pointer to *automatic* array `vals`, which *no longer exists* after the function returns.

*Any* use of the returned pointer will produce undefined behavior.

> This code is just to give you an idea of whats happening, there is nothing wrong with my actual implementation.

It's somewhat hard to believe that.

> `pthread_join(tids[i], &(vals[i])); /* Again, this could be wrong */`

That *is* wrong: `vals` is uninitialized at this point, so you are writing all over random memory.

> I don't know how to properly store, process, and print them in main.

Here is how:

```
  void *vals[NUM_THREADS];
  ..
  for (i= 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(tids[i], &vals[i]);
  }
  for (i= 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    int *p = (int *)vals[i];
    total1 += p[0];
    total2 += p[1];
      ... etc.
  }
```